# ¿Como usar fontAwesome Icons o Sweet Alert icons en Sweet Alert 2 Vue?

Tags: vue.js, alertdialog, sweetalert, font-awesome, sweetalert2

Estoy intentando mostrar un icono de SweetAlert2 de esta librería [vue-sweetalert-icons](https://github.com/JorgenVatle/vue-sweetalert-icons) y también lo intente con [fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome), pero en ninguna de las ocasiones no tuve éxito y no hay documentación muy clara de como podría hacerlo.

con font awesome no se muestra absolutamente nada en pop up y con vue-sweetalert-icons obtengo un `[Object, Object]` en el espacio donde debería ir el icono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La unica solucion que encontre fue crear un gif con el preloader que queria mostrar y incrustarlo en el sweetalert como una imagen de esta forma:

```
this.$swal({
  imageUrl: '/img/loading-gif.png',
  imageWidth: 100,
  imageHeight: 100,
  imageAlt: 'loading icon',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  showCancelButton: false,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false,
  title: 'Descargando documento',
  text: 'Por favor espere mientras el documento solicitado es descargado.',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya es un poco tarde para responder supongo pero aquí la solución a los que estás buscando.
Y para empezar, no se puede añadir un icono distinto a los preestablecidos por los editores a no ser que modifique el código fuente.

La solución es Ajax.

y sería lo siguiente.
Usaré bootstrap, fontawesome y sweetalert2
**Primero.-** un archivo html o php como gustes que tenga el formato de la pantalla que quieres PEJ: vista.html

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
  <h1><span class="fa fa-book"></span></h1>
  <p>Aqui debe de ir el contenido o lo que quieras</p>
</div>
```

**Segundo.-** en el archivo dónde estás ejecutando las acciones sea el html, php o un archivo js a parte irá lo siguiente (una vez ya estés haciendo tus funciones de click o cualquier otro)

```
$.ajax({
  url:'vista.html',
  success:function(MiVista){
   Swal.fire({
    html:Mivista,
    showConfirmButton:false
   });
   Swal.showLoading();
})
```

y listo, ahora tu alerta personalizada tiene lo que quieres.

Repito, el ajax ya debe de estar dentro de la función que estás ejerciendo.

**Edit** Ahora bien, si lo que quieres usar son los iconos que vienen por defecto de sweetalert2 es lo siguiente

```
Swal.fire({
  icon:'info',/*'error','warning','success','question'*/
  title:'Espere a que se complete',
  showConfirmButton:false
});
Swal.showLoading();
```